# (ILSpy) System.BadImageFormatException: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid

Tags: exe

How to overcome the error message while trying to open the `exe` in ILSpy:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.
   at Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadOptionalHeaders(UInt16& subsystem, UInt16& dll_characteristics)
   at Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadImage()
   at Mono.Cecil.PE.ImageReader.ReadImage(Disposable`1 stream, String file_name)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at ICSharpCode.ILSpy.LoadedAssembly.LoadAssembly(Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Is the executable packed or what to do?

Comment: What about you posting the exe so we can know what's wrong in your particular case?

Comment: (either the exe is corrupted, or ILSpy cannot read it)

Comment: By the way: it suffices to tag the question with appropriate tags. It's not necessary to put `(ILSpy)` in the title.

Comment: Are you sure it's a .net binary?

Answer (score 1):

If the program runs, it should be possible to dump the module from memory, after it was reconstructed to original state while loading it to memory.